# MPDF charset issue

Tags: mpdf, html-to-pdf

How to change charset in MPDF 6.0? When I echo $html variable everything is fine, but when I turn it into pdf then I have question marks instead of some special characters...

```
$html = '<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' . $style . '</head><body>
' . $page4 . ' źźźżżżżżż
</body>
</html>
';


include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('c',array(297,210)); 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'iso-8859-2';
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: What if you create your mPDF object without the `c` mode parameter? also, A4 is a default, you can do `$mpdf = new mPDF();`

Comment: Yeah "c" was issue, I've solved it yesterday forgot to post answer :)